# Testing Procedure and Process

Tags: php, testing

I'm working with a small team to make web based software. We have modules which are more or less independent pieces of code.  While the whole site is not complete, we have a couple modules done, so I'd like to get one of the team members on testing.

My question is: Is there an established testing process, procedure or tools that others utilize?  If so, can you share it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into [Test-Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) as a practice and [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) as test tools.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're concerned about Unit-Tests (and your questions sound so that you want to test individual units like functions or classes), you can make use of [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/). It's an X-Unit type of testing framework for PHP code.

With processes you probably mean integration tests, e.g. how multiple components work together with each other. That's possible, too with PHPUnit.

Many PHP Developers are using PHPUnit and it's well documented.